# CET FATAL: role "root" does not exist in postgresql-9.3-main.log postgreSQL

Tags: linux, postgresql, cron

```
less /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
```

looking inside postgresql log file I've found many lines with this:

```
CET FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

After many google research I've only found the way to create user , but that is not what I'm looking for.
How can I check what kind of postgresql cron job is this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I have a solution.

```
CEST FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

This appears also every 5min in my postgres log. 
I have searched with htop to find this nasty program that pollutes my logs.
It was monit! Monit checks postgres every 5min if it is still running or not. 
Here the monit config (monitrc):

```
 check process postgres with pidfile /var/postgres/postmaster.pid
 group database
 start program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql start"
 stop  program = "/etc/init.d/postgresql stop"
 if failed unixsocket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432 protocol pgsql 
 then restart
 if failed host 111.111.111.111 port 5432 protocol pgsql then restart
```

Now I have simply kicked it from my config, because I don't know how to fix it.
I think the problem is the unixsocket thing and the access right.

Comment: https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/PostgreSQL & http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~aa4t-nngk/monit2_en.html#pgsqltest

Comment: but for postgresql version 12  pg_hba.conf for root user:
```local root  root  ident```

Answer (score 0):

It must be a connection attempt from root. To check the cron, You can login as root and check in cron list which one is attempt to connect to postgres without specifying `--user valid_user` or `-U valid_user`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but after testing root cron jobs using
    `crontab -l -u root`
there is no postgres command related

Comment: maybe it's not in cron, but run manually from root user. Or it could be the postgres command lie down on the script, so it will not appear by issuing crontab -l.

Comment: I agree, how can I intercept the command starting from the root user? it appear every 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

From the filename of the log file I'm guessing you've installed postgres from a `.deb` package.

If that's the case the cron job that's giving the problem is not from the deb package, it's one you have created locally.

Comment: Ok, I've checked with `crontab -l` and there is only one command to empty swap memory file, no postgres custom command related. How can I find from witch application start this root login attempt?